# python regex search pattern

Tags: python, regex

I'm searching a block of text for a newline followed by a period.

```
pat = '\n\.'
block = 'Some stuff here. And perhaps another sentence here.\n.Some more text.'
```

For some reason when I use regex to search for my pattern it changes the value of pat (using Python 2.7).

```
import re
mysrch = re.search(pat, block)
```

Now the value of pat has been changed to:

```
'\n\\.'
```

Which is messing with the next search that I use pat for.  Why is this happening, and how can I avoid it?

Thanks very much in advance in advance.

Comment: You need to use a raw string. do `pat = r'\n\.'` This is a duplicate of a bunch of questions on here, but the gist is that since both Python and Regex use ```\``` as an escape character, you use the raw string syntax to tell Python NOT to treat it as an escape, that your string is LITERALLY backslash-n-backslash-dot, not newline-backslash-dot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra slash isn't actually part of the string - the string itself hasn't changed at all.

Here's an example:

```
>>> pat = '\n\.'
>>> pat
'\n\\.'
>>> print pat

\.
```

As you can see, when you print pat, it's only got one `\` in it. When you dump the value of a string it uses the `__repr__` function which is designed to show you unambiguously what is in the string, so it shows you the escaped version of characters. Like `\n` is the escaped version of a newline, `\\` is the escaped version of `\`.

Your regex is probably not matching how you expect because it has an actual newline character in it, not the literal string `"\n"` (as a repr: `"\\n"`).

You should either make your regex a raw string (as suggested in the comments).

```
>>> pat = r"\n\."
>>> pat
'\\n\\.'
>>> print pat
\n\.
```

Or you could just escape the slashes and use

```
pat = "\\n\\."
```

Comment: Ah.  Thanks much.  r"" should have occurred to me.